# Linq for sorting C#

Tags: c#, linq

The weathers very hot so my brains not working so good. Whats the best way to sort this with LINQ? Note the sorting takes place based on the "C" but applies to the "M"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Compare
{
    public class M
    {
        public IList<C> Columns = new List<C>();
    }

    public class C
    {
        public bool SortByMe { get; set; }
        public string Guid { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IList<M> list = new List<M>();

            M one = new M();
            one.Columns.Add(new C() 
            {
                SortByMe = true,
                Guid = "5"
            });
            one.Columns.Add(new C()
            {                
            });
            one.Columns.Add(new C()
            {             
            });

            M two = new M();
            two.Columns.Add(new C()
            {             
            });
            two.Columns.Add(new C()
            {
                SortByMe = true,
                Guid = "2"
            });
            two.Columns.Add(new C()
            {             
            });

            M three = new M();
            three.Columns.Add(new C()
            {

            });
            three.Columns.Add(new C()
            {
                SortByMe = true,
                Guid = "100"
            });
            three.Columns.Add(new C()
            {

            });

            list.Add(one);
            list.Add(two);
            list.Add(three);

            //Then sort the M by the occurrence of a C with SortByMe true.

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `orderby`? What did you try, and what was the result?

Comment: I am trying to effectively sort the Parent objects based on a single record on the value of a single record on the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean that each `M` instance would have a *single* `C` instance, among its `Columns` collection, whose `SortByMe` property is `true`; and you want to sort your collection of `M` instances by the `GUID` values of these `C` elements?

```
list = list.OrderBy(m => m.Columns.Single(c => c.SortByMe).Guid).ToList();
```

Note that, since `GUID` is `string`, your sort will be alphabetical (`"100"`, `"2"`, `"5"`), not numeric. If you want it to be numeric, you need to throw in an `int.Parse`.

**Edit**: Version performing numeric sort:

```
list = list.OrderBy(m => int.Parse(m.Columns.Single(c => c.SortByMe).Guid)).ToList();
```

And logically-equivalent query syntax:

```
list =
(
    from m in list
    orderby
    (
        from c in m.Columns
        where c.SortByMe
        select int.Parse(c.Guid)
    ).Single()
    select m
).ToList();
```

You need to take into account that any failure of the original assumptions – such as more than one `C` element in a given `Columns` collection having its `SortByMe` set to `true`, or a `GUID` value that is not a valid integer – would cause the entire expression to fail.

Comment: Where would you add the int.Parse

Answer (score 1):

```
        var query = from m in list
                    let c = m.First(x => x.SortByMe)
                    orderby c.Guid
                    select m;
```